# How do I pass anonymous lists to calling method from static method?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, anonymous-types, jsonresult

```
public JsonResult GetReport(string reportSelected, string firstDateGiven)
        {
            _context = new ReportDB();

            var theResults =
                    miPolicyTransactions.Select(
                        x =>
                            new
                            {
                                PolicyReference = x.PolicyReference,
                                TransactionType = x.TransactionType
                                ...
                                }).ToList();

                var theadColumns = new[]
                {
                    new {columnName = "Policy Reference"},
                    new {columnName = "Transaction Code"}
                    ...
                }.ToList();

                return Json(new { data = theResults, columns= theadColumns }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Above is what I started with which works, but I have used a dictionary func to simplify the calls and create other content.

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<IReportDB, string, JsonResult>> functions = new Dictionary<string, Func<IReportDB, string, JsonResult>>
                {
                    {  "New Business by Agent last 3 Months(set)", NewBusinessAgentLast3Month},                   

                    {  "New Business by Agent last 7 days  (set)", SomeOtherMethodName}
                    };

 private static JsonResult NewBusinessAgentLast3Month(IReportDB context, string parameters)
        {

        _context = new ReportDB();

        var theResults =
                miPolicyTransactions.Select(
                    x =>
                        new
                        {
                            PolicyReference = x.PolicyReference,
                            TransactionType = x.TransactionType
                            ...
                            }).ToList();

            var theadColumns = new[]
            {
                new {columnName = "Policy Reference"},
                new {columnName = "Transaction Code"}
                ...
            }.ToList();

            return ??????????????????????????
```

I cant return a Json object as I get an error

> An object reference is required for the non static field, method,
>   property.  Cannot access non-static Json in static context.

Can I avoid creating a concrete type with a concrete type lists for each , but still pass both anonymous lists to the calling method to in turn by returned as a JsonResult which is used in my Jquery file?  Would you use List or is there another way??

Comment: can't you make the functions static?

Comment: Essentially no as this breaks OOP, which the client wants.  Invariably I'm only having the static methods as  Dictionary<string, Func<> insists on them (throws an error otherwise).

Comment: are you saying you are getting a compilation error, or run time exceptions? when you try to make the Funcs in the dictionary initialization non-statc?

Comment: Intellisence and compilation errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your functions (like `NewBusinessAgentLast3Month`) to return `object`. You should then pass this value to the `Controller.Json` method which will create a `JsonResult` that you can return from the controller.

The question marks in your code should be replaced with the same anonymous type you used before your refactoring.

Comment: I went with dynamic, which is essentially @Martins advice.  Thank you very much.